# I want to add a circle which stays the same size

Tags: carto

As stated in my title, I want to draw a circle with a fixed diameter. It should not change when I am zooming in or out. How do I do that? (I am using the CartoDB Service).

I am trying to visualize how many points on the map are within a 10 mile range for example.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Should the circle always be of the same diameter on the screen (pixel wise)? Or do you always be of the same distance of 10 miles?

Answer (score 1):

It might be tricky to do it with CartoCSS. I would create a polygon with many vertices that represents a circle. So

```
WITH circle AS (SELECT ST_Buffer(the_geom::geography, 1609.34)::geometry as the_geom)
SELECT the_geom, ST_Transform(the_geom, 3857) the_geom_webmercator FROM circle
```

I use the WITH just to clean it up and give you both the_geom and the_geom_webmercator in your result, it isn't necessary if you just want it on the map. All you need is the_geom_webmercator so you can add the transform to the first statement and be done.

::geography lets you work in meters. You then buffer you point (the_geom) by 1609.34 meters or roughly 1 mile. You then cast it back with ::geometry and it is 4326. Finally, I transform it with 3857 so that we can render it on the map.